# Injection of UserDetailsManager and AuthenticationManager fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to inject UserDetailsManager and AuthenticationManager into a controller(AuthenticationController):

```java
@RestController
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationController(
            UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userDetailsManager = userDetailsManager;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

The configuration file should have already done that:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

   @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

However, I get the error when I start the app (SpringChatServerApplication)

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in haohanyang.springchat.server.controllers.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

It worked when I had only one SpringBootApplication. The error occurred after I put the Client SpringBoot application into the project. But those configuration files are in the same context as the server app. According to project facets in the IDE.

[image]

The structure of project is

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of the Bean method that returns the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` to `UserDetailsManager`. Also, remove `@EnableWebSecurity` from the controller; it's already present on your configuration.

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    // ...
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```